# Cannot set initial url for main-view

Tags: javascript, html, html-framework-7

For the app I'm making, when the user first enters the app, the default home page is loaded (let's call it `index.html`). After the user signs in, they are routed to another page of the app (let's call this `feed.html`).

When the user leaves the app and decides to come back later, but is still logged into the app, I want the user to automatically see `feed.html` when the app loads, rather than `index.html`.

Is there any way I can do this? I have tried changing the default url dynamically and in the html as indicated [here](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/views.html#default-view-url), but `index.html` keeps loading instead of `feed.html`.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

```
var mainView;
if (localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn") !== null){
    // If already logged in
    mainView = myApp.addView(".view-main", {
        url: "feed.html"
    });
}
else {
    mainView = myApp.addView(".view-main", {});
}
```

So this is my code. According to the documentation, setting the `url` parameter when instantiating the main view should set the default url of the page to load when the view loads, but `feed.html` doesn't load.

Before this, I would forward the user to `feed.html` after `index.html` loads using the router:

```
mainView.router.load({
    url: "feed.html"
});
```

but I would rather have the user land on `feed.html` instead of `index.html` if possible.

Comment: when user signin store some value in the localStorage and remove that value on logout. Next time when the user came for that variable if present then load feed.html else index.html

Comment: I think I wrote my question poorly. I already do what you stated. It's actually setting the default URL that's the problem. Let me post the code I currently have first.

Comment: addView is function of which library

Comment: I'm using [framework7](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/views.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have use previous version of framework7. its solve the problem